# Extract list of imported modules from haskell module

Tags: haskell, haskell-src-exts

I want to use [haskell-src-exts](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts) to parse haskell source module. But it requires fixities of all the operators to be specified. So I need to have a list of all imported modules to extract fixities for all the operators in scope.

So, I need to parse module to get list of imported modules; and I need the list of imported modules to parse the module :(

The question: how to parse haskell source module without parsing it? Is there any other parser I can use? How [hlint](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hlint) solves the issue?

`haskell-src-exts` provides [function](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskell-src-exts/1.13.5/doc/html/Language-Haskell-Exts-Parser.html#v%3agetTopPragmas) to extract top level pragmas. I need something similar, but for imported modules.

Comment: The `haskell-src-exts` parser returns a `Module`, whose single constructor appears to take a `[ImportDecl]` as one of its arguments; is this not exactly what you want?

Comment: @DanielWagner Sorry, I was not clear. I want to avoid parsing it twice. Without fixities `Module` will contain wrong AST for module body.

Comment: I don't think hlint resolves the operator fixities, it just looks at a single file. Also see http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/darcs/hlint/hlint.htm ("Why doesn't HLint know the fixity for my custom !@%$ operator?")

Comment: @Yuras If this is something you care about, you may have to write your own code for it. But I bet the maintainer of `haskell-src-exts` would gladly accept patches to parse certain frequently-useful prefixes of a module.

Comment: Another approach would be to parse without fixities `parseFileWithMode defaultParseMode{ fixities =Nothing }`, and then once you've looked at the imports use  `Language.Haskell.Exts.Fixity.applyFixities` to make the AST follow the right fixities. Who knows if that plays nicely with fixity decls you can put in `let`.

Comment: @aavogt I'll not be able to try it for the next 2 weeks, but it looks like the solution. Could you please make it a real answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach would be to parse without fixities `parseFileWithMode defaultParseMode{ fixities =Nothing }`, and then once you've looked at the imports use `Language.Haskell.Exts.Fixity.applyFixities` to make the AST follow the right fixities. Who knows if that plays nicely with fixity decls you can put in let